# Confirm if authtoken is null and redirect to login if it does not exist

Tags: android, authentication, oauth

I have the below implementation in my home activity to check if an authtoken exists and if not redirect to the login activity. It gets the job done however there is an issue...

**Scenario**

I launch the app for the first time (authtoken obviously null),the confirmLogin method (which is called always gets fired,finds no authtoken and displays the login...but there is like a 5-15 second delay in doing this in which time the user is in the homepage and back to login page again. How can I instictively make sure thet the homepage is not viewed as the method checks for the authtoken?

```
private void ConfirmLogin(String accountType, String authTokenType) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures(accountType, authTokenType, null, this, null, null,
            new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                @Override
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                    Bundle bnd = null;
                    try {
                        bnd = future.getResult();
                        authToken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                        if (authToken != null) {
                            String accountName = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                            mConnectedAccount = new Account(accountName, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);

                        }
                        else{
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AppHome.this, AppLogin.class);
                            intent.putExtra(AppLogin.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                            intent.putExtra(AppLogin.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS);
                            intent.putExtra(AppLogin.ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_NAME);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_LOGIN);
                        }




                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        finish();
                        Log.e("Account Login terminated", e+"");                            
                    }
                }
            }
    , null);
}
```